# How to transform a process model into a code?

Tags: algorithm, loops, process, bpmn

I need to tranform this scheme of the process flow into a code using only the functions in the table. I think, that there should be a loop after a decision if C1 or C2 is true, but I do not know how to exit the loop afterwards. Bold circle in the right is the final state.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nDHO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The break statement can be used to jump out of a loop.

IF (C1 != TRUE AND C2 != TRUE)
BREAK;